# Smooth shading not working for curve elements

Tags: modifiers, shaders, bezier-curves

I used an array aswell as curve modifier in blender 2.8 to create a room out of an object, applied all the modifiers (no more active modifiers now), removed all doubles and activated the smooth shading option, but there are still artifacts present when rendering.

Adding a simple UV Sphere and setting it to smooth shading, there are no artifacts present whatsoever.

Anyone know what is the diffrence?

Thanks.

Edit: Solved it. Simply use "shade smooth" before using the array modifier. Afterwards it will not update.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With curve selected go to *Curve Data Properties* and increase **Resolution Preview**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I actually solved the shading issue by using the shade smooth option on the mesh piece _ before _ using the array modifier. Afterwards it just wont update.

Comment: @Jonas10080 Please don't add thank you as comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted